Summary and parameter not appearing
Currently creating a doxygen using a md file however summary and param are now shown on the doxygen html but methods and titles are shown anyone knows why?
# API List
## Initialization (class name: ABC)
'''csharp
    /// <summary>
    /// XYZ 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enableLog"></param>
    public static void Init(bool enableLog);
'''

doxygen version 1.12.0
doxygen -x Doxyfile
PROJECT_NAME           = ABC
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
INPUT                  = Documents/WebPages/API-List.md
FILE_PATTERNS          =
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = API-List.md
HTML_OUTPUT            =
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES


Which version of doxygen are you using (doxygen -v)? Which settings did you use (i.e. the result of doxygen -x Doxyfile). please add a more complete example. First guess might be that EXTRACT_STATIC=YES is missing.

Yeap just done thanks for the reminder!

Example? from what is in the question I don't know what is is the cs file. I don't believe # are comment signs in C#

hi yes its from C# but I am just creating the doxygen through this API-List.md file where I put all my api documentation inside the API-List.md file to create the doxygen

OK so have a markdown file with the mentioned content. I think the image gives the clue, the comments should be present as comments so set STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS=NO

the comments do appear but as it is without any formatting I have updated the photo

A markdown file is for giving textual information which can include code fragments, but the code is not interpreted as being code in the sense of used code, so you would need here a real cs file that is also interpreted and shown by doxygen.

so it wouldn't be possible to create the doxygen through just 1 md file and I would have to go through every file that has the api method?

I have to think about the possibilities. Will take a few hours...

okay thanks so much for the help nonetheless appreciate the inputs

Not a 100% satisfying answer but maybe something to live with.
This works in the current 1.12.0 version.
In markdown we have special comment signs <!--!, from the documentation (Just above https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html#htmlentities):

When using the, Doxygen, special HTML style comments, i.e. <!--! ... –>, it is not seen as comment but as if the ... part is just in the documentation. This is useful to specify Doxygen commands inside a markdown file like:
<!--! \page pg1 The page -->

which will be ignored by regular Markdown processors, but Doxygen will interpret this as if there was written:
\page pg1 The page 


This works for quite a few doxygen commands, though odd ones out are e.g. \brief and also the XML style documentation is supported except of course here also e.g <summary>.
For the doxygen commands there are alternatives by means of ALIASES.
I used the example:
Doxyfile
QUIET = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = NO
ALIASES = my_brief="\par **Brief** ^^"

aa.md
# API List
## Initialization (class name: ABC)
```csharp
    /// <summary>
    /// XYZ
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enableLog"></param>
    public static void Init(bool enableLog);
```

<!--!
\my_brief XYZ
\param enableLog The param
-->
```csharp
    public static void Init(bool enableLog);
```


<!--!
<summary> XYZ </summary>
<param name="enableLog"></param>
-->
```csharp
    public static void Init(bool enableLog);
```

Which results in:

As you can see the last XYZ is a bit displaced as it is at the top of the page.

Thanks! I will try it out and see what is the best option. Appreciate the input
